# LItecoin clone blockchain peer connected but blocks not being downloaded

Tags: blockchain, cryptocurrency, litecoin

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.hackster.io/pjdecarlo/how-to-make-a-cryptocurrency-using-litecoin-v0-15-source-fb5e82) for creating a litecoin clone for learning purposes. So everything worked well and even started mining, coins were sent successfully, but the problem was when I added another node to connect to this node. I added `addnode` in both their config with the IPs of each other and restarted the daemon. The cli `getpeerinfo` shows the other node is connected but the blocks are not being downloaded. Can't seem to figure out why. Any idea, if some information you seem is missing, I'm more than happy to provide.

> Error: connect() to ip:port failed after select(): Connection refused (111)

But the port is open on Amazon, nmap shows it's open, ufw is inactive for now. Still this error. Can't seem to find out why.

UPDATE: connection refused error fixed when I added `-listen` when running the daemon.

But now it throws,

> 2018-08-09 14:39:34 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 5040 seconds ago)

Answer (score 0):

try it again on a no aws server. Amazon is known for configurations which only work after paying some extra dosh

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).